# I don't want to open the word document each time the greeenshot captures the image. Is there a way to do that?

Tags: greenshot

I save the output file of [Greeenshot](https://getgreenshot.org/)  to a Word document. I don't want to open the Word document each time the [Greeenshot](https://getgreenshot.org/) app captures an image.  Is there a way to write the file from Greenshot without opening Word, the way you can pipe STDOUT to a text file ?

(a la `DIR *.RTF /S > RTFLIST.TXT`)

Comment: If you are saving as a Word file, it needs to open Word. This is the same as applications I use for example, create an Excel file in QuickBooks and it must open Excel. That is the way Office works.

Answer (score 0):

A review of Greenshot's

- [FAQ](https://getgreenshot.org/faq/)
- [Help files](https://getgreenshot.org/help/)
- [Git repository](https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot/blob/develop/README.md)

does not show such a capability. So, I checked with the authors  https://greenshot.atlassian.net/browse/FEATURE-1249  and they said to choose the second option in the pop-up list, Save Directly.... (which requires you make saving as a Word file the default in the Preferred File Output Settings).

[image: Greenshot's pop-up Save dialog]

It's a pretty nifty program. Thanks for mentioning it!